# Prove $f(x) = x^2 +ax+ 1$ factors

Tags: elementary-number-theory

**Prove** that if $a$ is any integer and the polynomial $f(x) = x^2 +ax+ 1$ factors (poly mod 8), then $f(x)$ is in fact a square; so what that means is that $f(x) ≡ (x + c)^2$(poly mod 8) for some non-negative integer $c<8$.

Then my question is also that what can be the possible values of a? Meaning that, for which non-negative $a$ less than 8 does $f(x)$ factor?

Comment: What do you mean with "poly mod 8"?

Comment: @PaoloLeonetti a polynomial f(x) with integer coefficients which factors

Comment: Assume $b,c$ are the factors of $f$ then $x^2+ac+1 = (x-b)(x-c)$. What does this tell you about $a,b,c$?

Comment: Be more explicit please: every polynomial of $n$ degree can be decomposed $\mathbb{C}[x]$ in $n$ factors. So, we have $p \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$, and are you searching for all values of $a$ integers such that $p=hg$, with $h,g \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ non-costant? I still dont get the meaning of "mod 8"

Comment: @Winther All should be the same

Comment: Expand the product and compare the two sides (mod $8$). Use that if $Ax \equiv B \mod 8$ for all $x$ then $A\equiv 0$ and $B\equiv 0$.

Comment: Ok I got it, thanks winther.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are searching all the integer values of $a$ such that 
$$x^2+ax+1 = (x-\alpha)(x-\beta)$$
in $\mathbf{Z}/8\mathbf{Z}[x]$, for some $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbf{Z}$. In particular $\alpha\beta \equiv 1\pmod{8}$, so that they are both odd, and $\beta=1/\alpha$. Moreover, $a$ has to be equal to $-(\alpha+\beta)$ (therefore, $a$ has to be an even number). Recalling that if $d$ is odd then 
$$d^2 \equiv 1\pmod{8}\implies \frac{1}{d}\equiv d\pmod{8},$$
we get that the polynomial can be rewritten, in $\mathbf{Z}/8\mathbf{Z}[x]$ as
$$x^2-\left(\alpha+\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)x+1=x^2-2\alpha x+1 = (x-\alpha)^2.$$

Comment: I just started learning this. I am not familiar with the notation: Z/8Z[x]. Can you explain this to me please.

Comment: You take the quotient ring $\mathbf{Z}/8\mathbf{Z}$ (i.e. the integers modulo 8), and adjoin the variable $x$. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_ring

Comment: Okay thanks. Can you look at my other question too?